# Image cropping tool of DCE in TYPO3 not working

Tags: typo3-10.x

Here is the configuration of my Image field.

```
<config>
    <type>inline</type>
    <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
    <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
    <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
    <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
    <foreign_match_fields>
        <fieldname>{$variable}</fieldname>
    </foreign_match_fields>
    <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
    <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
    <overrideChildTca>
        <columns>
            <uid_local>
                <config>
                    <appearance>
                        <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                        <elementBrowserAllowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,pcx,tga,png,pdf,ai,svg</elementBrowserAllowed>
                    </appearance>
                </config>
            </uid_local>
        </columns>
        <types type="array">
            <numIndex index="2">
                <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
            </numIndex>
        </types>
    </overrideChildTca>

    <minitems>0</minitems>
    <maxitems>99</maxitems>

    <appearance>
        <useSortable>1</useSortable>
        <headerThumbnail>
            <field>uid_local</field>
            <width>45c</width>
            <height>45</height>
        </headerThumbnail>

        <enabledControls>
            <info>1</info>
            <dragdrop>1</dragdrop>
            <hide>1</hide>
            <new>0</new>
            <sort>0</sort>
            <delete>1</delete>
        </enabledControls>

        <createNewRelationLinkTitle>LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference</createNewRelationLinkTitle>
    </appearance>

    <behaviour>
        <allowLanguageSynchronization>1</allowLanguageSynchronization>
    </behaviour>

    <dce_load_schema>1</dce_load_schema>
    <dce_get_fal_objects>1</dce_get_fal_objects>
</config>
```

And the code for the Image is this:

```
<f:for each="{field.bgimage}" as="image" iteration="iterator">
    <div class="banner" style="background-image: url('fileadmin{image.identifier}');" ></div>
</f:for>
```

The problem here is that the cropping tool/ Image manipulation tool, which appears in the back end, is not working.
[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg3ko.png)

I can crop the image with this, but no change is happening with my image.

If anyone knows pls help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<f:for each="{field.bgimage}" as="image" iteration="iterator">
    <div class="banner" style="background-image: url('{f:uri.image(src: '{image.uid}', treatIdAsReference:1, width: '1920c')}');"></div>
</f:for>
```